# ActiveRecord commands sequence to count associated records from different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Client, User and Action models.
Client belongs to User through has_and_belongs_to_many association. Action belongs to Client. I need to retrieve Clients belonging to specific user(id=1) and count associated with the Client Actions of particular type(action_type=1) 
I have the following SQL query, which does the job pretty well

```
SELECT clients.*, count(CASE WHEN actions.action_type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS client_actions FROM clients, actions, clients_users WHERE clients.id=actions.client_id AND clients.id=clients_users.client_id AND clients_users.user_id=1 GROUP BY clients.id
```

Which effectively queries database for clients data, and counting associated objects. However I'm struggling to understand how to wrap it into ActiveRecord commands sequence, so I could use Paginate for the results. (at the moment I run the query using find_by_sql)

Answer (score 0):

One potential option would be to add something like this on your Client model:

```
def self.find_clients(user_id, action_type)
  clients = Client.scoped({})
  clients = clients.scoped(joins: :users, conditions: ["user_id = ?", user_id] )
  clients = clients.scoped(joins: :actions, conditions: ["action_type = ?", action_type] )
  clients = clients.count
end
```